# want to add nested form beside the form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I have nested-form for add images and it's working fine to.

When i do add new pic then it will add new form below the previous form.

but i want to add new form beside the previous form.

Under the `nested_form_for`

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
                            <%= f.fields_for :images do |image_form| %>
                              <%= image_form.collection_select :version_name, Image::VERSION_NAMES.keys.collect{|version_name| [version_name, version_name]}, :first, :last, :include_blank => "Please Select" %> <br /><br />
                                <div class="image-upload">
                                  <label for="file-input">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                                  </label>
                                  <%= image_form.file_field :picture,:'data-role'=>"none" ,:onchange=>"readURL(this);" ,:id=>"file-input" %>
                                </div>
                              <%= image_tag image_form.object.picture.url,:class=>"img_prev", :style => "width:80px;height: 70px" %><br />
                              <%= image_form.link_to_remove "Remove this Pic" %><br />
                            <% end %>
                        </div>
                        <br /><br /><%= f.link_to_add "Add a picture", :images ,:id=>"add_pic"%>
                      </div>
```

[image]

you can see in image it's coming below previews image but i want this beside previous image.

if anyone have Idea help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this function working using this code.

this is worked for me

```
 <%= f.fields_for :images do |image_form| %>
                          <div class="col-xs-6">
                              <%= image_form.collection_select :version_name, Image::VERSION_NAMES.keys.collect{|version_name| [version_name, version_name]}, :first, :last, :include_blank => "Please Select" %> <br /><br />
                                <div class="image-upload">
                                  <label for="file-input">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                                  </label>
                                  <%= image_form.file_field :picture,:'data-role'=>"none" ,:onchange=>"readURL(this);" ,:id=>"file-input" %>
                                </div>
                              <%= image_tag image_form.object.picture.url,:class=>"img_prev", :style => "width:80px;height: 70px; display:none;" %><br />
                              <%= image_form.link_to_remove "Remove this Pic" %><br />
                          </div>
                        <% end %>
                        <br /><br /><%= f.link_to_add "Add a picture", :images ,:id=>"add_pic"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if we can see the css. However it looks like your "image-upload" div or the form around it is the width of the window so your new form appears below the previous image rather than sitting side by side. If you reduce width of this div it should sit side by side.